# How to check files in folder and after check files in sub-folders

Tags: python-3.x, file, jpeg

I have such a structure:

```
Root_folder:
    |
    |__sub_folder1
    |
    |__sub_folder2
    |
    |__sub_folder3
    |
    |__Photo_file.jpeg
```

Before I was checking sub_folders for photo_files, but if I have a jpeg_file in root I do get an Error.

```
def get_photos(path):
    photos = []
    photos_path = []
    for folders in os.listdir(path):
        for jpeg in os.listdir(path + folders):
            photos_path.append(path + folders + '/' + jpeg)
            photos.append(jpeg)
    return photos,  photos_path
```

How do I append jpegs from root and jpegs from sub_folders to the list?

```
def get_photos(path):
    photos = []
    photos_path = []

    for folders in os.listdir(path):
        if re.match('.*\.jpeg|.*\.jpg|.*\.png', folders):
            photos_path.append(path + folders)
            photos.append(folders)
    for folders in os.listdir(path):
        for jpeg in os.listdir(path + folders):
            photos_path.append(path + folders + '/' + jpeg)
            photos.append(jpeg)

    return photos,  photos_path
```

This is as far as I got, checking if root has jpegs, than append them. But what should be the logic for sub_folders?
Rightnow it tryes to use jpeg_file name as subfolder as well, thus an Error is appearing

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
def get_photos(path):

    photos = []
    photos_path = []

    for folders in os.listdir(path):
        if re.match('.*\.jpeg|.*\.jpg|.*\.png', folders):
            photos_path.append(path + folders)
            photos.append(folders)
        else:
            for jpeg in os.listdir(path + folders):
                photos_path.append(path + folders + '/' + jpeg)
                photos.append(jpeg)

    return photos,  photos_path
```